# DotCMS page API does not return "layout" field

Tags: dotcms

I want to use the Layout-as-a-Service (LaaS) feature of DotCMS. This approach is documented in 
 https://dotcms.com/blog/post/more-than-a-headless-cms-layout-as-a-service-in-dotcms and also
in https://github.com/fmontes/dotcms-page.

Both articles suggest, that the DotCMS page API should return a field called "layout" in the response, e.g. to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/page/json/test-page

`test-page` is a page, which is using a standard template. By standard template, I mean template created with "Template Designer", with a 20% sidebar on the left, one 100% width column, both containing "Blank container".

No matter what I try, the "layout" field is never part of the response. All I get is this:

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "entity": {
    "canCreateTemplate": true,
    "containers": ...,
    "numberContents": 2,
    "page": ...,
    "site": ...,
    "template": ...,
    "viewAs": ...  },
  "messages": [],
  "i18nMessagesMap": {},
  "permissions": []
}
```

I tried DotCMS version 5.2.0 and also 5.2.3.
Is this perhaps a feature of the Enterprise edition only?

**Edit:** What I expect:

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "entity": {
    "canCreateTemplate": true,
    "containers": ...,
    "layout": {
      "width": "responsive",
      "title": "mytemplate1",
      "header": true,
      "footer": true,
      "body": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "columns": [
              {
                "containers": [
                  {
                    "identifier": "b5ea1513-7653-4602-a729-97cd8dd099b6",
                    "uuid": "1582123997023"
                  }
                ],
                "widthPercent": 100,
                "leftOffset": 1,
                "styleClass": null,
                "preview": false,
                "width": 12,
                "left": 0
              }
            ],
            "styleClass": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "sidebar": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "identifier": "b5ea1513-7653-4602-a729-97cd8dd099b6",
            "uuid": "1582123991866"
          }
        ],
        "location": "left",
        "width": "small",
        "widthPercent": 20,
        "preview": false
      }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the answer myself.

I checked the source code. In `com.dotmarketing.portlets.htmlpageasset.business.render.page.HTMLPageAssetRenderedBuilder#build` there is following piece of code:

```
        final TemplateLayout layout = template != null && template.isDrawed() && !LicenseManager.getInstance().isCommunity()
                ? DotTemplateTool.themeLayout(template.getInode()) : null;
```

So the answer is, that you can use LaaS promoted by DotCMS only if you have a non-community licence.

Answer (score 0):

Your page needs to use a "layout template" in order to retrieve the layout from dotCMS - using an advanced template won't work.

Also, layouts are part of the enterprise edition.  Make sure you have a license in order to use the layout manager.

Comment: I explicitly stated, that my page does not use an advanced template. It is using a standard template, build using Template Designer, which is a feature available even without a licence.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I got access to a DotCMS site with an enterprise licence. I created exactly the same page with same template and the Page REST API returns the layout in the response. But the same REST API does not return the layout on my local (licence free) installation of DotCMS. Is the absence of the licence the difference?